# Is the smallest primitive root modulo p a primitive root modulo p^2?

Tags: nt.number-theory, primitive-roots

Let $p \ne 2$ be a prime and $a$ the smallest positive integer that is a primitive root modulo $p$. Is $a$ necessarily a primitive root modulo $p^2$ (and hence modulo all powers of $p$)? I checked this for all $p < 3 \times 10^5$ and it seems to work, but I can't see any sound theoretical reason why it should be the case. What is there to stop the Teichmuller lifts of the elements of $\mathbb{F}_p^\times$ being really small?

Comment: Well, the probability of a primitive root $r$ modulo $p$ not to be primitive modulo $p^2$ is $1/p$ (there is exactly one $a$ modulo $p$ such $(r+ap)^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod{p^2}$). So, your search for larger $p$ will hardly lead to a counter example. But I've never heard on a theoretical background towards this.

Comment: Since finite fields can not be ordered, I am sometimes a little bit annoyed by properties defining the smallest (natural) integers $a$ whose reduction modulo $p$ has a certain property in the finite field $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$. 


Comment: Well, but among the finite fields the prime field is a bit special, and it indeed has a canonical total order (which is not compatible with the field operations).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is not true in general.  See http://primes.utm.edu/curios/page.php/40487.html for the example, 5 mod 40487^2.

Comment: Oops! There was a typo in my computer program, so I missed this example. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Good reason not to trust computer-based evidence.

Comment: Victor, I checked after all myself: $5^{40486}\equiv 1 \pmod{40487^2}$, but I am not very surprised after learning the story about Wolstenholme primes (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolstenholme%27s_theorem): only two are known with the smallest 16843 of about the same magnitude as 40487.

Answer (score 23):

The key term here is: Wieferich prime base $a$.

What you observed can be presented to children in the following form:  if $p$ is a prime *greater than 5* and the fraction $1/p$ has decimal period $d$, numerical tables show $1/p^2$ has decimal period $dp$, $1/p^3$ has decimal period $dp^2$, and generally the decimal period  of $1/p^k$ is $dp^{k-1}$. For example, 1/13 has decimal period 6, 1/169 has decimal period $78 = 6 \cdot 13$, and 1/2197 has decimal period $1014 = 6 \cdot 13^2$.

This works for primes below 100, but if you search far enough you will find a counterexample.  The first one is $p = 487$: 1/487 and $1/487^2$ both have decimal period 486. The second counterexample is $p = 56,598,313$. (!!) This list has been Sloaned: http://oeis.org/A045616.

For a general article about this business, see http://www.jstor.org/stable/3219294.

Within algebraic number theory, this phenomenon appears when you compute the ring of integers of ${\mathbf Q}(\sqrt[n]{2})$, which turns out to be ${\mathbf Z}[\sqrt[n]{2}]$ for all $n \leq 1000$.  With that evidence you might guess the ring of integers is always ${\mathbf Z}[\sqrt[n]{2}]$, just like the ring of integers of ${\mathbf Q}(\zeta_n)$ is always ${\mathbf Z}[\zeta_n]$.  But in fact it's not always true.  There are $n > 1000$ such that ${\mathbf Z}[\sqrt[n]{2}]$ is not the full ring of integers of ${\mathbf Q}(\sqrt[n]{2})$. If you search for Wieferich primes to base 2 you will find them.

Comment: For the general statement: c.f. "Problems in Algebraic Number Theory", Murty and Esmonde, second edition, Exercise 5.6.12

Comment: +1 for the verb "to Sloane"

Comment: @FilippoAlbertoEdoardo: I've heard Noam Elkies refer to a book as being Dovered.

Answer (score 10):

Primes $p$ for which $p^2$ divides $q^{p-1}-1$, for various small values of $q$, are often important in elementary attacks on Fermat's Last Theorem. See Lenstra and Stevenhagen's article "Class Field Theory and the First Case of Fermat's Last Theorem" in the book *Modular Forms and Fermat's Last Theorem*, for a quick survey. I don't see any reason, from this perspective, that $(q^{p-1}-1)/p$ should be particularly unlikely to be divisible by $p$. Nonetheless, that literature might give you some hints.

[Crandall, Dilcher and Pomerance](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1372002) (see Section 3) present data suggesting that $(2^{p-1}-1)/p \mod p$ looks uniformly distributed in $[-p/2, p/2]$. They suggest that the rarity of primes with $p$ dividing $(2^{p-1}-1)/p$ has no deeper reason than that, if $a_p$ is a random sequence indexed by primes, one only expects $p$ to divide $a_p$ for roughly $\log \log N$ primes less than $N$, and $\log \log$ of the computable range is quite small. Replacing $2$ by the smallest primitive root mod $p$ may exhibit similar behavior.

Comment: David, they are more important for Catalan's equation! Such pairs are crucial in the final solutions, while for the FLT they only do the "1st case".

Answer (score 5):

This would probably fit in the eventual counterexamples page too.

http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2009-78-266/S0025-5718-08-02090-5/home.html

Comment: The main result of the cited paper was anticipated by Steven Glasby in a post to the Number Theory mailing list on 22 April 2001. See http://listserv.nodak.edu/cgi-bin/wa.exe?A2=ind0104&L=nmbrthry&T=0&F=&S=&P=2674

Comment: The link didn't work when I tried it just now, but one can find the post by searching the nmberthry archive at the listserv for Glasby.

Comment: For the record (in case the links disappear again):
A. Paszkiewicz, "A new prime $p$ for which the least primitive root  
mod $p$ and the least primitive root mod $p^2$ are not equal",
*Math. Comp.* **78** (2009), 1193-1195.  The prime $p$ is $6692367337$;
the least primitive root mod $p$ is $5$, but $5^{p-1} \equiv 1 \bmod p^2$
(the least primitive root mod $p^2$ turns out to be $7$).

Comment: @Noam, sorry, I meant the link I posted to the Glasby post to the nmbrthry listserv --- that's the one that seems to be broken.

Comment: Just in case the link gets outdated: that prime counterexample is 6692367337.